# Refactoring a project to get stable and trunk branches using bazaar

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

I'm relatively new to VCS and especially Bazaar so I started my project without using it, using a structure like this

```
+project_root
     +scripts
         +bin                   # Binaries for easy testing
         +dev                   # Sources root
             +package_folder
             +package_folder
             ...
```

But I've been told that VCS are the best thing since set theory, so I've tried to put it under Bazaar, using [that](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.3/en/user-guide/starting_a_project.html) I've done a

```
cd scripts/dev
bzr init
bzr add
bzr commit -m "Initial import"
```

Now (how cool is that) I just `bzr commit -m "spam"` whenever I feel like it and `bzr push` when I don't trust my HDD.

But now that I have some stable and distributable code, I have set up a project at launchpad and I'd like to have some `trunk` branch where I could make unstable commits just to backup and a `stable` branch for the users to use.

That is to say I'd just have to spawn some command and it will update `stable` at the current state of `trunk` when I have a stable version I want to distribute, bundling all intermediate revisions into one.

How can I do this, if possible without refactoring my folder structure, and what should be my project structure on launchpad according to the usuals conventions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is more about Launchpad than bzr.

You can set up your trunk as default branch on launchpad, or you can set up your stable branch as default branch on Launchpad. Open the series page for your project:

https://launchpad.net/PROJECT/+series

Click on trunk series. You should be able to select the branch you want to be associated with trunk series. https://launchpad.net/PROJECT/trunk/+edit Let's select your trunk here.

Now you should return to series page and create a new series let's call it "stable".
https://launchpad.net/PROJECT/+addseries

For stable series you should select another branch, let's select your stable branch.

So now, when you or your users will use short URL like `lp:PROJECT` then it will access your trunk branch. If another short URL will be used: `lp:PROJECT/stable` then it will access your stable branch.

`lp:PROJECT/XXX` will access the branch associated with XXX series.

Comment: Well, thanks. But my question was more specifically about how I could push revisions of `trunk` that are stable in `stable` without copying the whole history of `trunk` revisions every time.

Comment: @Evpok On launchpad you can get it to stack on your trunk branch so that when you push stable it will not push all the history again. Outside of launchpad you can use shared repositories to get the same type of optimization.

Comment: @Evpok: I haven't seen question about push in your original post. As AmanicA said the branches on Launchpad will be stacked, therefore reducing the size of history pushed. Only the first push to trunk will transfer the entire history. The stable branch (after you configure trunk branch as your branch for trunk series) will be automatically stacked on trunk. You can control the stacked behavior on initial push with `--stacked-on` command-line option.